# bloquear/desbloquear powershell

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell

Tengo este script bat para bloquear/desbloquear powershell pero no funciona en x64 (y a veces tampoco en x86) y a veces logro bloquearlo pero no desbloquearlo (No se pudo iniciar CLR, HRESULT: 80070005.) y haciendo un Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

```
MachinePolicy = Restricted
UserPolicy    = Undefined
Process       = Unrestricted
CurrentUser   = Undefined
LocalMachine  = Unrestricted
```

Lista de comandos para bloquear/desbloquear

```
:: Restore PS
%windir%\system32\takeown.exe /f %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
%windir%\system32\takeown.exe /f %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe
%windir%\system32\icacls.exe %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe /Grant *S-1-1-0:F
%windir%\system32\icacls.exe %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe /Grant *S-1-1-0:F
%windir%\SysWOW64\takeown.exe /f %windir%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
%windir%\SysWOW64\takeown.exe /f %windir%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe
%windir%\SysWOW64\icacls.exe %windir%\sysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe /Grant *S-1-1-0:F
%windir%\SysWOW64\icacls.exe %windir%\sysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe /Grant *S-1-1-0:F

:: Disable PS
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell" /v ExecutionPolicy /t REG_SZ /d Restricted /f
%windir%\system32\takeown.exe /f %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
%windir%\system32\takeown.exe /f %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe
%windir%\system32\cacls.exe %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe /E /P %username%:N
%windir%\system32\icacls.exe %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe /Deny *S-1-1-0:F
%windir%\system32\icacls.exe %windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe /Deny *S-1-1-0:F
%windir%\SysWOW64\takeown.exe /f %windir%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
%windir%\SysWOW64\takeown.exe /f %windir%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe
%windir%\SysWOW64\icacls.exe %windir%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe /Deny *S-1-1-0:F
%windir%\SysWOW64\icacls.exe %windir%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe /Deny *S-1-1-0:F
```

En otras palabras. Quisiera saber **cómo se bloquea/desbloquea el programa powershell.exe por línea de comandos con un .bat**.. gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál es la salida que esperas? ¿Qué resultados obtienes actualmente?

Comment: Que se bloquee o desbloquee el programa powershell. El resultado es que no sucede nada cuando ejecuto eso en cualquier windows x64. solo x86 funciona

Answer (score 2):

Solo tienes que añadir el comando para crear un registro (para poder usar ps)
y borrarlo para bloquear, claro todo como administrador

**PERMITIR PS**

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds
\Microsoft.PowerShell" /v  "ExecutionPolicy" /t REG_SZ /d "Unrestricted" /f
```

**BLOQUEAR PS**

```
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds
\Microsoft.PowerShell" /v  "ExecutionPolicy" /f
```